# Typeahead Functionality

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm about to do a cool auto complete field and am thinking of using Typeahead.js

I understand with Typeahead.js I can do custom html templates for the suggestions which is great.

But I'm wondering can I also render whatever html I like for the value that is chosen from the suggestions?

I want to display a little image alongside the value chosen.

Just wanted to check it can be done before I deep dive typeahead.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you mean; perhaps you want to decorate the choice with an image after the choice has been made?

That said, you probably want to look at the "Custom Events" section of the [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md).  I suspect one of `typeahead:cursorchanged`, `typeahead:selected` or `typeahead:autocompleted` will help.  As usual, your callback receives the event, from the event you can dig out whatever you need.

I wouldn't worry about a deep rabbit hole. It's a simple library, you'll probably be able to figure out fairly quickly if what you want is possible.